# Add class to jquery dialog buttons

Tags: jquery, css, class

I want to add css class on buttons of a jquery dialog box.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#messageBox p').html('bla bla bla. Ok?'); 
      $('#messageBox').dialog({
        modal : true,
        buttons: {
          'Yes': function() {
            doSomething();
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }, 
          'No': function() {
            doAnotherThing();
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

For example, I would like add ".red" class on my "yes" button.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
buttons: [
            {
               text: "Submit",
               "class": 'submit_class_name',
               click: function() {                     
                  $(this).dialog("close"); 
               }
            },
            {
               text: "Cancel",
               click: function() { 
                  $(this).dialog("close"); 
               }
            }
          ]
```

Comment: This is the best answer! Note: use quotes around the class attribute, on iPad it throws an error (probably 'cause class is a reserved (key)word)

Comment: Same error in IE8 too. Solved with `"class"` instead of `class`

Answer (score 8):

I've got the solution, thanks to Rich :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#messageBox p').html('bla bla bla. Ok?'); 
      $('#messageBox').dialog({
        modal : true,
        dialogClass: 'dialogButtons',
        buttons: {
          'Yes': function() {
                doSomething();
                $(this).dialog('close');
          }, 
          'No': function() {
                doAnotherThing();
                $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      });
    });
$("div.dialogButtons div button:nth-child(1)").addClass("oneCssClass");
$("div.dialogButtons div button:nth-child(2)").addClass("anotherCssClass");
```

Solved!

Answer (score 5):

There's a **dialogClass** option of the **dialog** function you can use to specify a css class for the dialog itself.  You can give it a unique class name and use this class name to get a reference to any child elements of the dialog.  Then, use the selectors to either get a reference to the child buttons by position or by the text it contains (probably more efficient to use the former).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [addClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass) function?

Comment: But where to add that addclass function?

Comment: same answer like phoenix... Where can I put the addClass function, because buttons are made by jquery dialog and buttons don't have ID's.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. Very similar to nico's solution but add the styling to the open function on the dialog:

```
open: function () {
                // add style to buttons (can't seem to do this via the button definition without breaking IE)
                $(".someDialog .ui-dialog-buttonset button:first").not(".buttonPrimary").addClass("buttonPrimary");
                $(".someDialog .ui-dialog-buttonset button:last").not(".buttonSecondary").addClass("buttonSecondary");
                $("#someDialog").focus();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where i needed to add some styling to a button on the fly before the dialog was shown.  Getting to the button was not very simple so i figured out a very simple way of getting to the buttons.  During the creation of the dialog buttons i just gave them an 'id' and then i could get a reference to them with the usual jquery selector...  `$("#btnDelete").addClass("disabled")`

```
buttons: [{
        id: "btnDelete",
        text: "Delete",
        click: function () {
            Delete();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }, {
        id: "btnSave",
        text: "Save",
        click: function () {
            Save();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }, {
        id: "btnCancel",
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
```

Answer (score -4):

.addClass function

Comment: yeah, i know this function... but I don't know how to use it in my case.